# Using input_file_name, take substring between underscores without file extension

Tags: file, apache-spark, pyspark, substring, file-extension

I want to take a substring from a filename every time a new file is coming to us for processing and load that value into file. The task here is like suppose we are receiving many files from X company for cleansing process and the first thing what we need to do is to take substring from the file name.

For Example: the file name is 'RV_NETWORK_AXN TECHNOLOGY_7737463273272635'. From this I want to take 'AXN TECHNOLOGY' and want to create a new column with name 'COMPANY NAME' in the same file and load 'AXN TECHNOLOGY" value into it. The file names change, but the company name will every time be after the second underscore.

Comment: you have to provide more context. what kind of files are these? csv files?

Comment: Hi @DataWorld, could you please provide dataframe with the filename path and expected output.

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi the filename and output i have already shared in post itself. Please refer to the SS that is the output we want

Comment: Hi @iambdot yes the files which are coming for processing are csv files

Comment: hi ,
I am using this code to fetch the desired output but i am also getting .csv added with my value which i want to remove

df_1=df_1.withColumn('COMPANY',F.split(F.input_file_name(),'_')[3])

for eg. AXN TECHMOLOGY.csv

Comment: how can i remove this .csv from end and take only String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment, you said that using `df_1 = df_1.withColumn('COMPANY', F.split(F.input_file_name(), '_')[3])` extracts `AXN TECHMOLOGY.csv`.

I'll suggest 2 options to you:

- You could use one more `split` on `\.` and using `element_at` get the 2nd to last element. In this case, splitting on `\.` works and on `.` doesn't, because this argument of `split` function is not a simple string, but a regex pattern; and unescaped dot `.` in regex has a meaning of "any character".

  ```py
  df = df.withColumn(
      'COMPANY',
      F.element_at(F.split(F.split(F.input_file_name(), '_')[3], '\.'), -2)
  )
  ```
- The following regex pattern would extract only what's after the 3rd `_` and potential 4th `_`, but  not including file extension (e.g. `.csv`).

  ```py
  df = df.withColumn(
      'COMPANY',
      F.regexp_extract(F.input_file_name(), r'^.+?_.*?_.*?_([^_]+)\w*\.\w+$', 1)
  )
  ```